# Why is the Farad unit so large?

Tags: capacitor, units

I have wondered this on and off for years, and was prompted to find out the answer:

Any time I've seen capacitors, they're listed with milli- or pico-Farad ratings. I understand that, nowadays, we have special purpose supercapacitors that package "whole" Farads into single components.

But, why on earth did "they" use such a large base value that for "most" applications you'd need something in the milli- to pico- range? It just seems ... unnecessarily skewed.

Comment: Like most modern units, farad is defined based on SI base units. It's 1F = 1 As/V. That's it. Nothing to answer here.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why is the unit for capacitance so large?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72326/why-is-the-unit-for-capacitance-so-large)

Comment: Same question could be posed regarding mass, which is already 'compensated' by the standard prefix kilo...

Comment: @Huisman but that's a base unit, and thus so defined. You'll notice that, for example, J is well definable with respect to kg without any further prefixes. Nice, isn't it?

Comment: because it's based on 1 second.